# Uri path is empty while capturing image?

Tags: android, image, camera

Uri path is `null`? How do I get the image URI path? My code is:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "Image File name");
mCapturedImageURI = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
Intent intentPicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intentPicture.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
startActivityForResult(intentPicture,CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

OnActivityResult method

```
if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
 String videoPath = getRealPathFromURI(mCapturedImageURI);
```

}

But still image path is `null` (null pointer exception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialise mCapturedImageURI before you can use it. Check the intent that is returned to onActivityResult:

```
@Override  
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{  
  // data will contain your URI
}
```

Comment: can u tell me how to check whether the intent is null or not.give me sample code.

Comment: You can put some effort in yourself. This questions is also a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453771/how-to-capture-user-image-in-android

Comment: the above code is working fine in sony xperia(2.3.3).but my problem is,it doesnt work in samsung tablet(2.2).give me some solution??

Comment: my logcat is displaying like this  02-07 17:27:33.921: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10384): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1337, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {web.org/web.org.Multipleimg}: java.lang.NullPointerException